# Custom login form to Facebook on an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, facebook, login-control

I'm trying to make an application that can connecto to facebook. I've found [Facebook Connect for iPhone](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone) and I don't like the login form that it has.

Is there any way to make a custom login form? Is there some api functions to call to login an user on Facebook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend *not* going this route.  I'd be suspicious of any app that's asking for credentials that's not using the de-facto standard login control.  If there is no standard control, then I have to take my chances with whatever the app presents, but in the case of Facebook, the standard control is part of Facebook Connect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of the other API's such as the [REST API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API#Login.2FAuth_Methods) and then create your own UI to capture the login credentials and call the REST API to login.