# custom connect my iphone app to facebook

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, facebook

Is there any option to make a custom login page to facebook from my app?
i know that i cant customize the default login page on the facebook SDK.

my proggramer sais that we can use it by php..
do apple will agree my app if it will have such connect like that?
My iPhone Proggramer said to me that it is possible to set up login window that send the username and password by "get" method and then connect to facebook by php facebook sdk, is it correct? 
thanks alot, Ive been looking long time for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to log in to Facebook using a username and password from a third party app,  Facebook's [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) code will prompt the user to log in if they haven't already

Comment: thats mean i have to use the FB SDK to connect users to my app by facebook?

Answer (score 1):

This is not very good idea to do that. Check my earlier answer:

[Can I prevent Facebook iPhone app from opening when using facebook SDK from my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155934/can-i-prevent-facebook-iphone-app-from-opening-when-using-facebook-sdk-from-my-a/6156008#6156008)

Comment: Also this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654482/custom-login-form-to-facebook-on-an-iphone-app